# Why can I set ownership with icals but not set-acl On 2K12R2?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, access-control-list

Why using `get-acl -Path 'C:\Program Files' | set-acl -Path 'D:\Program Files'` as an administrator tells me I am not allowed to set the ownership while using `icACLs "C:\Program Files" /save Perms.txt` then `icACLs D:\ /restore Perms.txt` works without errors ?

Comment: Can you post the error you receive?

Answer (score 1):

You stumbled over Security Tokens.

Since a while now Microsoft uses `TokenPrivilege` to manage deeper rights such as "Take Ownership" [see this list of token rights](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/privilege-constants)

I think `icACLs` gets those tokens correctly without your doing so.
In Powershell you need to get those tokens yourself.

There are multiple HowTos in the net. I personally use this one: https://www.raydbg.com/2017/Token-Privileges-in-PowerShell/

It works by loading some default Windows dlls (kernel32.dll and advapi.dll) and using those to give the current process the TokenPrivileges it needs. Those would be:
`SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege`